# Got SecurityException in Java

Tags: java

Why I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Unsafe
```

when I run my code

```
public class UnsafeString {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException {
        String obj = new UnsafeString().create();
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
    public String create() throws InstantiationException {
        return (String) sun.misc.Unsafe.getUnsafe().allocateInstance(String.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing that code? Programmers are strongly discouraged from using `sun.*` classes.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `Unsafe` directly. It involves some hacks to avoid the `SecurityException` (mainly getting the `Unsafe` instance via reflection).
Assuming that you're not doing something stupid, like using it in production code, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003871/how-do-i-get-the-instance-of-sun-misc-unsafe) a way to retrieve it.

There's also a rumor that it would become a part of the public API later on.